# Problems with compiling

Tags: compiling, autoconf

I am pretty new to this here but i hope to learn quick. Anyways, i am trying to install a open source software but i get an error when trying to build it.

it says

```
:~$ ~/trunk/src/autogen.sh
```

Preparing the Delft3D build system...please wait

Found GNU Autoconf version 2.69
Found GNU Automake version 1.14.1
Found GNU Libtool version 2.4.2
grep: Makefile.am: No such file or directory
grep: Makefile.am: No such file or directory

Automatically preparing build ... Warning: autoreconf failed
Attempting to run the preparation steps individually

Preparing build ... ERROR: aclocal failed

what is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

It seems your autoconf and automake packages are not up to date, did you try to update them? if not, you may run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and afterwards if your problem is still unsolved try to install autoconf and automake again:

```
sudo apt-get install automake
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```